# Получить две переменных из одной строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу бота, хочу вместо ручного отрезания команды (`cmd = cmd[7:]`) отрезать его как то автоматически. Думал на счет `temp, cmd = cmd.strip().split(" ")`, но получается я не могу использовать два или больше слов в команде, допустим `!пнуть кого-то` отработает правильно, а если `!пнуть кого то`, выдаст ошибку `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Я понимаю почему она выдается, но как можно сделать так, что бы можно было легко все вписать и без всяких заморочек

Думал над циклом, который удаляет просто первый элемент и создает новую строку, но думаю есть варианты более оптимизированее

Comment: `.split(" ", 1)`

Comment: Примените опцию `maxsplit` у `split()` - `.split(" ", maxsplit=1)`. Тогда он вернёт первый элемент до пробела и всё остальное. Но если пробела не будет, то будет обратная ошибка - будет слишком мало значений для распаковки.